# Решение математических выражений на objective C

Tags: objective-c

Как организовать функцию в программе, чтобы при вводе любой математической задачи типа 2+5(6*2)-184(6/5)*3 выдавало результат?

Если я зараннее знал, какое выражение будет, то не составило бы труда написать такую программу. А как организовать решение задачи, не зная зараннее, меня затруднило. Может, кто подскажет, в каком направлении искать, или пример какой-нибудь подобный приведет, там я уже сам разберусь. Благодарю.

Comment: начните с этого http://habrahabr.ru/post/50276/

Comment: @rava, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0):

Мне на ум последовательный разбор с двумя стеками операторов и чисел примерно так:

нашли число - заносим в стек чисел

нашли оператор - заносим в стек операторов

нашли еще число - в стек чисел

нашли еще оператор и он имеет меньший или равный приоритет (например 2 + 5 + ..., мы на втором плюсе), то берем последние два числа из стека чисел, берем последний оператор из стека операторов, считаем, записываем результат в стек чисел и продолжаем разбор, если же приоритет больше (2 + 5 * ...) - оператор в стек и далее так же пока не найдем оператор меньше последнего

Подозреваю, что примерно это же можно сделать при помощи построения дерева выражения где конечные узлы числа, а остальные узлы операторы

Касательно же obj-с - я не думаю что это какая-то языкоспецифичная задача, готового решения я точно не знаю, более того самый простой путь парсить строку посимвольно на мой взгляд перегнать ее в сишный массив char. Кстати, подсказка - числа в таблицах символов всегда (по крайней мере я не знаю исключений) последовательно идут, можно проверять не регуляркой, а что char между '0' и '9', ну а из символа число можно получить с помощью `с-'0'`.